# Adjust font size in rms:::plot.anova.rms

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am using the rms package for logistic regression using the example titanic dataset, `plot()` on an `anova` object can produce a figure like the following

[image]

My question is how can I make the text in the plot smaller (column names, chisquare statistic, p-values), I checked the internal function `rms:::plot.anova.rms` and see no such arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the titanic dataset, so here is a reproducible example using `iris`:

```r
library(rms)

iris2 <- within(iris, Sepal.Length <- Sepal.Length > 5.5)
model <- Glm(DF2formula(iris2), data = iris2, family = binomial)
plot(anova(model))
```

[image]

The function `rms:::plot.anova.rms` contains an ellipsis for passing arguments on to `plot`. Therefore, even though it is not a named argument, you can pass `cex` to control the text size:

```r
plot(anova(model), cex = 0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the dot argument before ...